# Ajax post doesn't send data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http-post

I built a vote system with ajax and php, and I send data to php page for saved data in db.
I tried to send data with ajax post and php.
My problem is the data is not send to the page.
My js code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajaxSetup({
    url: 'vote.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: 'false'
  });

  $('.vote').click(function(){
    var self = $(this); 
    var action = self.data('action'); 
    var parent = self.parent().parent();
    var imgid = <?=$array['id'];?>; 
    if (!parent.hasClass('.disabled')) {
      if (action == 'up') {
        parent.find('#image-like').addClass('disabled_up');
        $.ajax({data: {'imgid' : imgid, 'action' : 'up'}});
      }
      else if (action == 'down'){
        parent.find('#image-dislike').addClass('disabled_down');
        $.ajax({data: {'imgid' : imgid, 'action' : 'down'}});
      };
      parent.addClass('.disabled');
    };
  });
});
</script>
```

and my html code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="image-like" data-action="up" class="vote"></a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="image-dislike" data-action="down" class="vote"></a>
```

Comment: any error in your console

Comment: From where you're collecting $array['id'] to imgid?

Comment: if you inspect the network tab for the request in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c2PUL/1/) it seems fine... both `imgid` and `action` parameters are sent

Comment: Also, verify your vote.php page is properly functioning

Comment: if you in to vote.php its work but if i send data its not work !

Comment: Not to do with the question but `hasClass('.disabled')` should be `hasClass('disabled')`

Comment: Open the console, you probably have errors, at least `<?=$array['id'];?>` should cause an error, as it's probably an unquoted string, you're sometimes including the period in jQuery's ***Class methods, othertimes you're not, you're using `find()` to find ID's which should be unique, and you shouldn't have to use `find()` to find an ID, `void(0)` should be avoided, use preventDefault instead, and a bunch of other small errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use post method. This is not the correct code, but it's an idea, always works for me.

```
$('.vote').click(function(){
//Your vars
var data='voteup';
//Your actions... ddClass/removeClass...
$.post('vote.php',data,function(data){
//On your vote.php use "if($data=='voteup') else ;"
//And show message here...
alert(data);
});
return false;
});
```

---

example of vote.php

```
<?php
$data=$_POST['data'];
if($data=='voteup')
echo "You voted up!";
else echo "You voted down!";
?>
```

---

It's just an idea (:

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing this:

```
if (!parent.hasClass('.disabled')) {
```

to this:

```
if (!parent.hasClass('disabled')) {
```

#### Some Notes:

[From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/):

For `$.ajaxSetup()`

> Description: Set default values for future Ajax requests. Its use is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .post() function, you can set a callback when your action is done

```
jQuery.post(URL_TO_REACH, {ID_VALUE1 : 'my value' , ID_VALUE2 : 'my second value' })
                 .done(function( data_ajax ) {   // data_ajax : Your return value from your php script
                        alert( data_ajax );
                 })
              });
```

Hope this will help you

Official documentation : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/